# Синхронизация нескольких потоков с главным потоком приложения

Tags: c++, winapi, многопоточность

Есть несколько устройств, управляемых через последовательный интерфейс. Устройства одинаковые по сути, поэтому создал визуальный компонент для управления этими устройствами. Пока со стороны пользователя нет никаких действий, нужно проверять, все ли в порядке на устройстве, (делаю это в отдельном потоке). Если на устройстве возникает какое-то событие, необходимо, чтобы приложение методами визуального компонента обработало это событие. На момент разработки приложения количество устройств неизвестно и может быть любым < 128. Кроме того, есть потребность в дополнительном потоке (выстрелил забыл), который тоже должен управлять устройствами. Во время работы этого потока можно у пользователя отобрать управление, оставить только возможность  остановить поток.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону семафоров. В винде ими не пользовался, но думаю гугл выдаст достаточно примеров.

Comment: @ИгорьBujhm Делал так : Каждый объект(устройство) имеет свой поток. Используют совместный ресурс Com порт. С использованием общего ресурса (порта) проблем нет. Но когда объект в зависимости от результатов опроса начинает генерировать события, получается что в потоке обращаюсь к методам и свойствам    визуальных компонентов. Когда количество устройств больше 10 приложение начинает тормозить.

Comment: @ИгорьBujhm, прочитал повнимательнее (+ Ваш комментарий).

Похоже, Вам надо "обрабатывать" в GUI **не все события**. Видимо надо выбирать из очереди как можно больше событий (сколько возможно без ожидания), а потом отображать только последние (или часть). 

Но, без понимания задачи в целом, толковый совет здесь дать трудно.

Учтите, я понял так, что потоки устройств передают данные некому "главному" потоку (через очередь) и именно он ("главный поток") вызывает визуализацию.